# AttributeError: class Tk has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

hey guys i stuck on simple python GUI program

```
import Tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk
text_box = tk.Entry(window)


def save_text():
    str1 = text_box.get()
    fx = open("file1.txt", "w")
    fx.write(str1)
    fx.close()

btn1 = tk.Button(window, text="Save", command="save_text")
text_box.pack()
btn1.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

i this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Saket/PycharmProjects/guiform1/firstform.py", line 5, in <module>
    text_box = tk.Entry(window)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2385, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'entry', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1965, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1943, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: class Tk has no attribute 'tk'
```

Anybody having idea what am i doing wrong please help me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `tk.Tk` to create an instance:

```
window = tk.Tk()
              ^^
```

You will then have a `tk.Tk`-type object to interact with.